# Kazakhstan to China by train in 2019?

Tags: trains, china, kazakhstan

*Is it still possible to go from Kazakhstan to China by train?*

If I search on the [web site](https://www.railways.kz) of the national railway company Kazakhstan Temir Zholy, I don't find any connections to China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a train station in Khorgas which is at the border and has a border crossing.

This page here has a map with border crossings in the whole region:
[Border crossings on the Silk Road](https://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/)

Answer (score 3):

You can take go from Almaty 2 or Astana to Ürümqi by using the Kazakhstan Temir Zholy. From there you can probably reach the rest of China by using the China Railways trains.

I generally use [rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) to find trains in places where public transport is hard to figure out.